# Get details from another mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which would contain information about a certain month, and one column in that row would have mysql row id's for another table in it to grab multiple information from

is there a more efficent way to get the information than exploding the ids and doing seperate sql queryies on each... here is an example:

```
Row ID | Name | Other Sources
1        Test   1,2,7
```

the `Other Sources` has the id's of the rows from the other table which are like so

```
Row ID | Name | Information  | Link
1        John | No info yet? | http://blah.com
2        Liam | No info yet? | http://blah.com
7        Steve| No info yet? | http://blah.com
```

and overall the information returned wold be like the below

```
Hi this page is called test... here is a list of our sources
- John (No info yet?) find it here at http://blah.com
- Liam (No info yet?) find it here at http://blah.com
- Steve (No info yet?) find it here at http://blah.com
```

i would do this... i would explode the other sources by , and then do a seperate SQL query for each, i am sure there could be a better way?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your specific problem, but most of the time that "Other Sources" field is a separate relational table that stores an association between the two rows in TableA and TableB.  That allows joins to be made via SQL instead of dealing with comma separated values.  Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a classic many-to-many relationship.  You have pages and sources - each page can have many sources and each source could be the source for many pages?

Fortunately this is very much a solved problem in relational database design.  You would use a 3rd table to relate the two together:

```
Pages (PageID, Name)
Sources (SourceID, Name, Information, Link)
PageSources (PageID, SourceID)
```

The key for the "PageSources" table would be both PageID and SourceID.

Then, To get all the sources for a page for example, you would use this SQL:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM Sources s INNER JOIN PageSources ps ON s.SourceID = ps.SourceID
AND ps.PageID = 1;
```

Comment: what sql would make it possible to echo out results in all two tables?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily with your table structure. If you had another table like:

```
ID    Source
1     1
1     2
1     7
```

Then `join` is your friend. With things the way they are, you'll have to do some nasty splitting on comma-separated values in the "Other Sources" field.

Comment: your way seems like an alternative, is there not a way to avoid creating another table?

Comment: Yes, what you're doing already. There are ways to split up comma-separated values in SQL, but those roads lead to sadness.

Comment: @johnnnnnnnnny - There's really no other good alternative.  This is a very common pattern in database design, and this is pretty much the one-and-only way it is done :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious (been known to), but why are you using a single field in your first table with a comma-delimited set of values rather than a simple join table.  The solution if do that is trivial.

Comment: what do you mean? 
the first table will have lots of rows with different sources

Comment: Dominic gave a far more useful answer, which covers where I was going.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with these tables is that having a multi-valued column doesn't work well with SQL.  Tables in this format are considered to be [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), as multi-valued columns are forbidden in [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and above.

First Normal Form means...

> 1. There's no top-to-bottom ordering to the rows.
> 2. There's no left-to-right ordering to the columns.
> 3. There are no duplicate rows.
> 4. Every row-and-column intersection contains exactly one
>      value from the applicable domain (and
>      nothing else).
> 5. All columns are regular [i.e. rows have no hidden components such as
>      row IDs, object IDs, or hidden timestamps].
>
> —Chris Date, "What First Normal Form Really Means", pp. 127-8[4]

Anyway, the best way to do it is to have a many to many relationship.  This is done by putting a third table in the middle, like Dominic Rodger does in his answer.